# ¿Como se usa el for each en C#?

Tags: c#, poo

estoy cursando POO en la facultad y no termino de entender objetos, y ahora estoy teniendo problemas con el for each, entiendo que es para recorrer objetos,pero no entiendo bien la función. Si me podrían recomendar algún libro o tutoriales estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Puedes leer [foreach, in (C# reference)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

Comment: ``foreach`` es para recorrer los elementos de una colección de objetos y hacer algo con cada elemento de la colección. La documentación de Microsoft se encuentra aquí: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in

Comment: Tal como está la pregunta parece poco adecuada para el sitio. Hay innumerables recursos en español que podría explicarte a todos los niveles que es y como funciona un `foreach`. Tal vez si explicas específicamente cual es tu problema al entenderlo, podríamos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 2):

La sentencia `foreach` es una manera de recorrer cada elemento dentro de un objeto, la ventaja que es que tu código no necesita conocer la estructura interna del este.  El responsable de entregar los objetos en orden es la misma clase que estás iterando.

Los únicos requisitos para poder utilizar `foreach` sobre una instancia son:

- La clase implementa un método público llamado `GetEnumerator()`
- El objeto que devuelva `GetEnumerator()` implemente la propiedad `Current` y el método `MoveNext()`

Estas condiciones son forzadas a ser cumplidas si se implementa la interfaz `IEnumerable` o `IEnumerable<T>`.

Existen muchas clases en el framework de .NET que ya implementan estas interfaces como `List<T>`y `Array`, no necesitarás implementarlo tú mismo en la mayoría de los casos.